# Problem with core plot barchart plotting

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am constructing an application that plots a barchart.
when i wrote this line

```
num=(NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:index];       
return num;
```

in the method

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

it works properly
but i need to pass a float number to plot
for that i wrote

```
num=(NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:f1];
return num;
```

then all of the bars appears together

i tried to adjust the barofset and barwidth but no solution

can anyone help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these numbers are for the CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation field, you need to check the corresponding plot space range (xRange for vertical bars and yRange for horizontal). Make sure the location and length of the plot space range are appropriate for the range of numbers you're returning for this field. It sounds like the length is too large.